# Changing the content of a QTabWidget's widget, knowing only the tab index

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt5, tabwidget

How do I change the `QWidget` inside a tab of a `QTabWidget`, knowing only the tab index?

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_2_clicked()
{
    TextItem myitem = new TextItem;//is a class TextItem : public QWidget
    int tabindex = 2;
    ui->tabwidget1->//i don't have a idea to change widget of a Tab by tab index
}
```

Comment: What is it you want it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say what solution would best suit your problem since you don't explain much of it.

**A first approach** would be to wrap the content of each tab inside a container `QWidget`: when you want to change the content of one tab, you just have to change the content of the container `QWidget`.

Another approach would be to delete the tab with the old content and create a new one with the new content.

---

**EDIT:**
Here is a quick implementation of the first approach I mentioned above:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void buildTabWidget();

private slots:
    void changeTabContent() const;

private:
    QTabWidget* tab_widget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTabWidget>

void MainWindow::buildTabWidget()
{
    // The container will hold the content that can be changed
    QWidget *container = new QWidget;

    tab_widget = new QTabWidget(this);
    tab_widget->addTab(container, "tab");

    // The initial content of the container is a blue QLabel
    QLabel *blue = new QLabel(container);
    blue->setStyleSheet("background: blue");
    blue->show();
}

void MainWindow::changeTabContent() const
{
    // retrieve the QWidget 'container'
    QWidget *container = tab_widget->widget(0);
    // the 'blue' QLabel 
    QWidget *old_content = dynamic_cast<QWidget*>(container->children()[0]); 
    delete old_content;

    // create a red QLabel, as a new content
    QWidget *new_content = new QLabel(container);
    new_content->setStyleSheet("background: red");
    new_content->show();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    buildTabWidget();
    QPushButton* push_button = new QPushButton("Change content");
    connect(push_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(changeTabContent()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(tab_widget);
    layout->addWidget(push_button);

    QWidget *window = new QWidget();
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
    setCentralWidget(window);
}
```

Clicking the button `Change content` will delete the old content (the blue `QLabel`) in the tab, and will replace it by creating a new content (a red `QLabel`):

[image]

Comment: thank you for answer. ok i created another class something like this Mywidget:public QScrollArea and i added an object on my mainwindow tab i added something like this : Mywidget *mw =new Mywidget; ui->tabwidget->addtab(wm,"mywidget"); - and i added a public function in Mywidget ; void changelayout(int);//1 for layout 1 and 2 for layout 2 . and i used a function for tab widget but it isnot work. ui->tabwidget->Widget(2)->changelayout(2); //error please help me .

Comment: A code sample has been included in the previous answer. Regards.